# Has someone successfully imported DICOM images from Siemens recently?

Tags: import

When I try to import DICOM files from Siemens MR, I can successfully import the MetaInformation, but importing the image itself fails.

I have posted a small example dicom file:
[DICOM example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0p7c1d8ykcjgzk/example.dcm?dl=0)

In version 10.4 (Windows) or 11.2 (MacOS) I get the following:

```
Import["example.dcm"]
(*Output:
Import::fmterr: "Cannot import data as DICOM format."
Import::fmterr: "Cannot import data as DICOM format."
Import::nodta: "Insufficient data found for DICOM format."
*)
```

Importing MetaInformation kind of works:

```
meta=Import["example.dcm", "MetaInformation"];
(*Output:
Import::fmterr: "Cannot import data as DICOM format."
Import::fmterr: "Cannot import data as DICOM format."
*)
```

But a lot of tag names are not resolved, which are listed in the DICOM standard.

I've contacted Wolfram support more than a year ago, but didn't get a helpful resonse except

> you may be able to use BinaryReadList

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Comment: I don't know what that means but ref/format/dicom says "fully support DICOM files conforming to Section PS 3.10 of the DICOM standard." so if your images use this standard I can add a bug tag.

Comment: Section PS 3.10 is only one part of the standard. Data sets are described in section PS 3.5. The example DICOM file follows this standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 12.1 the file in question seems to be fully supported:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

After a bit of digging into the internals of Import I figured that some value representations were not handled correctly, as required by the DICOM standard. I would call this a bug, but don't have the reputation to set the flag. If I load the package for importing DICOM files manually

```
(*Pre-load the DICOM import package to be able to overwrite it. *)
Get[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Kernel", "SystemResources", $SystemID, "Convert", "Dicom.mx"}]]
```

I can overwrite the function ReadData to fix the problem:

```
(* Overwrite ReadData to fix the Switch Statement *)
System`Convert`DicomDump`ReadData[
  System`Convert`DicomDump`s_,
  System`Convert`DicomDump`info_,
  System`Convert`DicomDump`ExplicitVR,
  System`Convert`DicomDump`rules_
  ] := Module[
  {
   System`Convert`DicomDump`len,
   System`Convert`DicomDump`VR
   },

  System`Convert`DicomDump`VR = 
   BinaryReadList[System`Convert`DicomDump`s, "Character8", 2];
  If[
   MemberQ[System`Convert`DicomDump`VR, EndOfFile]
   ,
   Return[EndOfFile]
   ];
  System`Convert`DicomDump`VR = 
   StringJoin[System`Convert`DicomDump`VR];

  System`Convert`DicomDump`len = Switch[
    System`Convert`DicomDump`VR,
    (*Alternatives["OB","OW","SQ","UN","UT"],*)
    Alternatives["OB", "OD", "OF", "OL", "OW", "SQ", "UC", "UN", "UR",
      "UT"],
        Last[
     BinaryRead[
      System`Convert`DicomDump`s, {"Character8", "Character8", 
       "UnsignedInteger32"}]],
    Alternatives["AE",
                "AS", "AT", "CS", "DA", "DS", "DT", "FL", "FD", "IS", "LO", 
     "LT", "PN",
                "SH", "SL", "SS", "ST", "TM", "UI", "UL", "US"(*, "UT"*)
            ],
        BinaryRead[System`Convert`DicomDump`s, "UnsignedInteger16"],
    _,
        System`Convert`DicomDump`VR = "UN";
        BinaryRead[System`Convert`DicomDump`s, "UnsignedInteger16"]
    ];
  If[
   System`Convert`DicomDump`len === EndOfFile
   ,
   Return[EndOfFile]
   ];

  System`Convert`DicomDump`read[
   System`Convert`DicomDump`s,
   System`Convert`DicomDump`info,
   System`Convert`DicomDump`VR,
   System`Convert`DicomDump`len,
   System`Convert`DicomDump`rules
   ]
  ]
```

Note that I've left the incomplete set of alternatives as a comment.

With this modification, I can import the DICOM file correctly.

The unresolved tag names can be resolved with an additional set of replacement rules, which I've posted here:

[tagnames.m](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxqu8zsg4qumq4b/tagNames.m?dl=0)

I couldn't figure out how to inject this into the import package, so I've simply added it as an additional replacement:

```
meta = Import["example.dcm", "MetaInformation"];
(* Remove one long private meta information to make things nicer *)
metaShort =  meta /. tagNames /. ("(0021,1019)" -> l_List) :> ("(0021,1019)" -> Short[l]);
metaShort //. l : {_Rule ..} :> Grid[l //. (a_ -> b_) :> {a, b}
   , Alignment -> {Left, Top}
   , Frame -> True
   , Background -> {None, {{GrayLevel[0.9], GrayLevel[0.95]}}}
   ]
```

The result is a readable version of the meta information, only the private tag names are unresolved, as expected.